# query: cross product instead of join

Tags: sql, cross-product

I have two tables that I would like to join but I am getting an error from MySQL

```
Table: books
bookTagNum ShelfTagNum
book1      1
book2      2
book3      2

Table: shelf
shelfNum   shelfTagNum
1          shelf1
2          shelf2
```

I want my results to be:

```
bookTagNum ShelfTagNum shelfNum
book1      shelf1           1
book2      shelf2           2
book3      shelf2           2
```

but instead I am also getting an extra result:

```
book1      shelf2           2
```

I think my query is doing a cross product instead of a join:

```
SELECT `books`.`bookTagNum` , `books`.`shelfNum` , `shelf`.`shelfTagNum` , `books`.`title`
FROM books, shelf
where `books`.`shelfNum`=`books`.`shelfNum`
ORDER BY `shelf`.`shelfTagNum` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: I've tried to answer as best I can, but your question is a little confusing, since your example doesn't show a books.shelfNum or books.title columns, even though you reference them in your query. And your output has 3 columns even though you requested 4.

Comment: IMplicit joins are a very poor programming practice. They are subject to accidental cross joins and much harder to maintain (for instance was that a deliberate cross join or a bug?) They have been out of date since 1992 and there is no excuse to ever use one when a better, more desciptive, less open to bugs option is available.

Answer (score 9):

I think you want

```
where `books`.`shelfTagNum`=`shelf`.`shelfNum`
```

In order to match rows from the `books` and `shelf` tables, you need to have terms from each in your `where` clause - otherwise, you're just performing a no-operation check on the rows of `books`, since every row's `shelfNum` will be equal to its `shelfNum`.

As @fixme.myopenid.com suggests, you could also go the explicit `JOIN` route, but it's not necessary.

Comment: I think he wants books.shelfNum = shelf.shelfTagNum

Answer (score 5):

if you want to be sure you're doing a join instead of a cross product, you should state it explicitly in the SQL, thus:

```
SELECT books.bookTagNum,books.shelfNum, shelf.shelfTagNum, books.title
FROM books INNER JOIN shelf ON books.shelfNum = shelf.shelfTagNum
ORDER BY shelf.shelfTagNum
```

(which will return only those rows which exist in both tables), or:

```
SELECT books.bookTagNum,books.shelfNum, shelf.shelfTagNum, books.title
FROM books LEFT OUTER JOIN shelf ON books.shelfNum = shelf.shelfTagNum
ORDER BY shelf.shelfTagNum
```

(which will return all rows from books), or:

```
SELECT books.bookTagNum,books.shelfNum, shelf.shelfTagNum, books.title
FROM books RIGHT OUTER JOIN shelf ON books.shelfNum = shelf.shelfTagNum
ORDER BY shelf.shelfTagNum
```

(which will return all rows from shelf)

Comment: @fixme: the notation Steve used is perfectly acceptable to old-school SQL programmers, even if what you suggest is preferred.  It works correctly, too.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, The implicit join syntax is badly flawed and should not be acceptable to any professional programmer.

Answer (score 4):

FYI: If you rewrite your names to be consistent, things get a lot easier to read.

```
Table 1: Book
BookID     ShelfID  BookName
1          1        book1
2          2        book2
3          2        book3

Table 2: Shelf
ShelfID    ShelfName
1          shelf1
2          shelf2
```

now, a query to extract books to shelves is

```
SELECT 
 b.BookName,
 s.ShelfName
FROM
 Book b
JOIN Shelf s ON s.ShelfID = b.ShelfID
```

---

To answer the original question:

```
> where `books`.`shelfNum`=`books`.`shelfNum`
>        ^^^^^--------------^^^^^------------- books repeated - this is an error
```

the `WHERE` clause, as written, does nothing, and because your where clause isn't limiting any rows, you are indeed getting the cross product.

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL. Your where clause cannot possibly be `books`.`shelfNum`=`books`.`shelfNum`

And what are all those single quotes for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `books`.`bookTagNum` , `books`.`shelfNum` , `shelf`.`shelfTagNum` , 
   `books`.`title`
FROM books, shelf
where `books`.`shelftagNum`=`shelf`.`shelfNum`
ORDER BY `shelf`.`shelfTagNum` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Because the implicit JOIN condition was not properly stated the result was a cross product.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the problem you faced was with your ON condition. To specifically answer your question:

In MySQL, if you omit a JOIN, an INNER JOIN/CROSS JOIN is used. For other databases, it is different.  For example, PostgreSQL uses a CROSS JOIN, not an INNER JOIN.

Re: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

"In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise."